# Display numbers as localised words (.NET 5)

Tags: .net, localization, number-formatting, icu

I want to display numbers as localised words (11 == Eleven, Onze, Elf depending on language).

I know that .NET 5 uses the ICU library "under the hood" and that ICU has this capability, but I can't see any way in which it is exposed.

Am I missing something?

Comment: For an update: Saxonica is sponsoring development work on ICU-N which should eventually provide this capability.